# Using the Twilio API/SDK to create a basic phone app on iOS

Tags: ios, twilio

The Twilio documentation suggests it's possible to create a simple iOS app that places and receives calls. There is even a sample project.  The sample project called MonkeyPhone contains ARC errors so it refuses to run.

The broader question is, is Twilio the best API / platform to use to place and receive calls on an ios or android app?

Comment: i am also used twilio Api to my ios app project.it is working fine..

Comment: Were you able to get the HelloMonkey sample working that Twilio provides?

Answer (score 6):

For this you can use TCConnectionDelegate methods . It automatically handle your calling procedure.

Here is few step that u will have to follow.

1.> You need to create a twilio account first and get account sid and auth token 
[image]

2.> After that go to the Dev tools -> TWIML Apps

Create a new twiml app and create 
[image]

Please mention request URL for voice where you will pass phone number.

3.> Pass your phone number on to TCConnectionDelegate connect method

```
   YourTwilioDeviceClass *phone = appDelegate.phone;
   [phone connect:self.textFieldPhoneNumber.text];
```

4.> Now get authentication token by passing accountSid,authToken,appId to your auth.php file on server.

```
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark TCDevice Capability Token

    -(NSString*)getCapabilityToken:(NSError**)error
    {
        //Creates a new capability token from the auth.php file on server
        NSString *capabilityToken = nil;

        NSString *accountSid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accountSid"];
        NSString *authToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authToken"];
        NSString *appId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"appId"];

        //Make the URL Connection to your server

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yourauthfilepath.com/twillo/auth.php?accountSid=%@&authToken=%@&appSid=%@",accountSid,authToken,appId]];
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                             returningResponse:&response error:error];
        if (data)
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

            if (httpResponse.statusCode==200)
            {
                capabilityToken = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
            }
            else
            {
                //*error = [ConferencePhone errorFromHTTPResponse:httpResponse domain:@"CapabilityTokenDomain"];
            }
        }
        // else there is likely an error which got assigned to the incoming error pointer.

        return capabilityToken;
    }

    -(BOOL)capabilityTokenValid
    {
        //Check TCDevice's capability token to see if it is still valid
        BOOL isValid = NO;
       // NSLog(@"_device.capabilities %@",_device.capabilities);
        NSNumber *expirationTimeObject = [_device.capabilities objectForKey:@"expiration"];
        long long expirationTimeValue = [expirationTimeObject longLongValue];
        long long currentTimeValue = (long long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

        if ((expirationTimeValue-currentTimeValue)>0)
            isValid = YES;

        return isValid;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Device Network connect and disconnect

    -(void)connect:(NSString*)phoneNumber
    {
        // first check to see if the token we have is valid, and if not, refresh it.
        // Your own client may ask the user to re-authenticate to obtain a new token depending on
        // your security requirements.

        HelloMonkeyAppDelegate *appDelegate=(HelloMonkeyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        if (![self capabilityTokenValid] || (!appDelegate.isTokenGet))
        {
            //Capability token is not valid, so create a new one and update device
            [self login];
        }



        if (![self reachabiltyCheck])
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:CPLoginDidFailWithError, nil]];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];

            HelloMonkeyAppDelegate *appDelegate=(HelloMonkeyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            appDelegate.isTokenGet=FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary* parameters = nil;
            if ( [phoneNumber length] > 0 )
            {
                parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:phoneNumber forKey:@"PhoneNumber"];
            }

            NSLog(@"parameters ===%@",parameters);
            _connection = [_device connect:parameters delegate:self];
            [_connection retain];
        }


    }

    -(void)disconnect
    {
        [_connection disconnect];
        [_connection release];
        _connection = nil;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideCallingView" object:nil];
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark - TCConnection Delegate Methods

    -(void)connectionDidDisconnect:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Call disconnected");

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Disconnected", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];

    }

    -(void)connection:(TCConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed %@",[error description]);
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Error", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)connectionDidStartConnecting:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Calling..");
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Calling", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)connectionDidConnect:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"In call..");

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"In call", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        [_device release];
        [_connection release];

        [super dealloc];
    }
```

5.> Finally  use TCConnectionDelegate methods

```
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark TCDevice Capability Token

    -(NSString*)getCapabilityToken:(NSError**)error
    {
        //Creates a new capability token from the auth.php file on server
        NSString *capabilityToken = nil;

        NSString *accountSid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accountSid"];
        NSString *authToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authToken"];
        NSString *appId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"appId"];

        //Make the URL Connection to your server

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.e-home.com/twillo/auth.php?accountSid=%@&authToken=%@&appSid=%@",accountSid,authToken,appId]];
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                             returningResponse:&response error:error];
        if (data)
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

            if (httpResponse.statusCode==200)
            {
                capabilityToken = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
            }
            else
            {
                //*error = [ConferencePhone errorFromHTTPResponse:httpResponse domain:@"CapabilityTokenDomain"];
            }
        }
        // else there is likely an error which got assigned to the incoming error pointer.

        return capabilityToken;
    }

    -(BOOL)capabilityTokenValid
    {
        //Check TCDevice's capability token to see if it is still valid
        BOOL isValid = NO;
       // NSLog(@"_device.capabilities %@",_device.capabilities);
        NSNumber *expirationTimeObject = [_device.capabilities objectForKey:@"expiration"];
        long long expirationTimeValue = [expirationTimeObject longLongValue];
        long long currentTimeValue = (long long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

        if ((expirationTimeValue-currentTimeValue)>0)
            isValid = YES;

        return isValid;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Device Network connect and disconnect

    -(void)connect:(NSString*)phoneNumber
    {
        // first check to see if the token we have is valid, and if not, refresh it.
        // Your own client may ask the user to re-authenticate to obtain a new token depending on
        // your security requirements.

        HelloMonkeyAppDelegate *appDelegate=(HelloMonkeyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        if (![self capabilityTokenValid] || (!appDelegate.isTokenGet))
        {
            //Capability token is not valid, so create a new one and update device
            [self login];
        }



        if (![self reachabiltyCheck])
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:CPLoginDidFailWithError, nil]];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];

            HelloMonkeyAppDelegate *appDelegate=(HelloMonkeyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            appDelegate.isTokenGet=FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary* parameters = nil;
            if ( [phoneNumber length] > 0 )
            {
                parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:phoneNumber forKey:@"PhoneNumber"];
            }

            NSLog(@"parameters ===%@",parameters);
            _connection = [_device connect:parameters delegate:self];
            [_connection retain];
        }


    }

    -(void)disconnect
    {
        [_connection disconnect];
        [_connection release];
        _connection = nil;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideCallingView" object:nil];
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark - TCConnection Delegate Methods

    -(void)connectionDidDisconnect:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Call disconnected");

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Disconnected", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];

    }

    -(void)connection:(TCConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed %@",[error description]);
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Error", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)connectionDidStartConnecting:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Calling..");
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Calling", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)connectionDidConnect:(TCConnection*)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"In call..");

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"In call", nil]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showCallingStatusView" object:nil userInfo:dict];
    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        [_device release];
        [_connection release];

        [super dealloc];
    }
```

I hope it helps you. Please let me know if you fetching any problem.

Comment: the connection delegate methods are not been called

Comment: So the phone number to which we have to make the call is a Twillio generated number or else any phone number.